# MSbuild up-to-date check for generated files does not work as needed

Tags: msbuild, t4, csproj, incremental-build

I have a c# project which includes several generated files (by T4) which are later included in compilation. The generation of code files itself works fine, but unfortunately incremental build sees generated files as a 'changes since last build' and re-builds the project each time. (For me it is a problem, since a large part of solution is rebuilt each time).

The warning from MSbuild looks like

> The project does not appear up-to-date after a successful build: Input Compile item '...\DtoGenerator.generated.cs' has been modified since the last successful build started, not up-to-date. See https://aka.ms/incremental-build-failure.

Related part of the *csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
          <UpToDateCheckInput Remove="*.generated.cs" />
          <UpToDateCheckOutput Remove="*.generated.cs" />
          <UpToDateCheckBuilt Remove="*.generated.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="TextTemplateTransform" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
        <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" Command="dotnet t4 &quot;%(TextTemplate.FullPath)&quot; -P=&quot;$(ProjectDir)..\TextTemplating&quot; -I=&quot;$(ProjectDir)..\TextTemplating&quot;" />
    </Target>
```

I added ´UpToDateCheck*´ as per [link proposed in warning](https://aka.ms/incremental-build-failure), but it does not seem to work.

I have also seen the [other proposed solution](https://www.benjamin.pizza/posts/2022-11-28-incremental-t4-text-templating.html) where "<Compile Remove" is used, and it does seem to help with up-to-date check, but this way the generated files are not included in compilation.

Have anyone encountered similar problem? How can I change the *.csproj to have the files generated before build and included during compilation, but excluding them from incremental build check?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that you are not supporting incremental generation. Your `TextTemplateTransform` target doesn't have [inputs and outputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-incrementally?view=vs-2022) for the T4 files and the generated files, respectively.

Assuming that `@(TextTemplate)` is a collection of `.tt` files and that there is a one-to-one relation of `.tt` to `.generated.cs`, then modify the target definition as follows:

```xml
<Target Name="TextTemplateTransform" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"
  Inputs="@(TextTemplate)"
  Outputs="@(TextTemplate->'%(Filename).generated.cs')">
```

Is this a Windows specific build? You may want to consider using the Modeling SDK's text transformation targets file instead of writing and maintaining your own `TextTemplateTransform` target. See ["Invoke text transformation in the build process"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-in-a-build-process?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp).